# How do I remove a Flutter device in VSCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When running my flutter code it opens in form of a macOs application. It used to open in the ios simulator. How do I revert that one back to my default device? (*Not* using advmanager, but VSCode)

I tried running flutter devices but couldn't find a "set device" option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flutter run -d <device_name>`to start your flutter app on a specific device.

Or shutdown/unplugged unused devices